# Why I cannot log into jaeger-agent docker container?

Tags: docker-container, jaeger

The only container that I cannot get into and check what's inside is `jaeger-agent`, downloaded from [here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/jaegertracing/jaeger-agent/1.17/images/sha256-bb9ff8866bb8b5f1e6bdbfb76d36308a049fdf5bd2aa9234cc83d6df5c9dd22a?context=explore).

**Why is this so? How can I get inside?**

Ideally:

```
docker exec -it jaeger-agent bash
```

would let me in the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is super minimalist and I do not have the necessary apps on it.
However with newer versions things are better.